# JSON Node.JS buffer seperate json entities

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, if-statement

I am using MangoDB and upon querying my username, I get this response which is in JSON context. (there may be a simpler way to do this. but I need to be able to access each variable individually. Not to mention decrypt the password then verify it to what the user entered.

How I plan to do this is with IF statements, should work for my principle.

This JSON output is stored in the variable user

```
>[ { _id: 560734a53e04afd4029ab020,
username: 'archlinuxusa',
password: '9cb1e3525d22f14efd',
server: 'ftb',
admin: true,
__v: 0 } ]
```

when I use something like,  console.log(user._id) or console.log(user.password)
I get undefined.

Any ideas on this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `.findOne()` instead of `.find()`. The former returns a single result while the latter is purposed to return many results. Which is why the latter is returned as an array.

Comment: `user[0]._id`, `user[0].password`, etc. Also, note that "*decrypt the password*" isn't a safe approach. It should not be reasonably possible to retrieve the original password from your database if you're handling them correctly. Hash both the original given at registration and the input at login, compare the hashes to verify.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the encryption advice, this makes more sense to me.